# Parse Server bad json response error code 100

Tags: android, json, parse-platform, jsonexception

I am using this [Parse Server Guide](https://parse.com/docs/server/guide) to create a local instance of parse server. I download and set up the example and it runs perfectly, but when i try to use the android SDK i get this error

```
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens 

W/System.err﹕ com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: bad json response
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:290)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:308)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:137)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:133)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:908)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:715)
02-12 22:41:58.662    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:726)
02-12 22:41:58.674    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:818)
02-12 22:41:58.674    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$13.then(Task.java:806)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$15.run(Task.java:917)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ Caused by: org.json.JSONException: Value Cannot of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
02-12 22:41:58.682    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRESTCommand.onResponseAsync(ParseRESTCommand.java:298)
02-12 22:41:58.690    7211-7211/com.christoandrew.android.authens W/System.err﹕ ... 13 more
```

Here is my index.js

```
    // Example express application adding the parse-server module to expose Parse
// compatible API routes.

var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGOLAB_URI

if (!databaseUri) {
  console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/authens',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'UBXrCTUXuXf6fEBpbE7sHBamq4b0RdQcASFTHxo9',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'ghFiFWGtdymY3oXqWDTDBz6RyW7XdMyWzjXoJjFb', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  clientKey: '4m2WpkkGCX77w3FNq3JWT74nVgRKNsgTj10Q1s4t',
  //restAPIKey: 'b7gUiB4cI7JeKLqKCWCkTZbBX4YA9S7xlQuwmUqX',
  //javascriptKey: '0qBhikhxV8ZtM95o1zTLFhhiuuLGiwDVcTxyvNdw',
 // dotNetKey: 'rc0uYDFU3Bo5U24PlBxKMBX7GpsHj8QHJLLVgsFg',
});
// Client-keys like the javascript key or the .NET key are not necessary with parse-server
// If you wish you require them, you can set them as options in the initialization above:
// javascriptKey, restAPIKey, dotNetKey, clientKey

var app = express();

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('I dream of being a web site.');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

This is how i initialize

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(getString(R.string.parse_app_id))
            .clientKey(getString(R.string.parse_client_key))
            .server("http://10.0.3.2:1337/parse")
            .build());
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
```

as in the tutorial. I am using genymotion as my virtual device running at 10.0.3.2. Is there something i am missing or is this a general issue.

**Update**

If i use curl from cmd works perfect

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: UBXrCTUXuXf6fEBpbE7sHBamq4b0RdQcASFTHxo9" -H "X-Parse-Client-Key: 4m2WpkkGCX77w3FNq3JWT74nVgRKNsgTj10Q1s4t" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @json.txt http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet still trying

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found a solution.
Instead of this

```
.server("http://10.0.3.2:1337/parse")
```

use this

```
.server("http://10.0.3.2:1337/parse/")
```

Comment: thats what i did too check my answer

Comment: To be explicit, ensure there is a trailing `/` to your server url. Silly mistake, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: wow thanks. i never would have caught this, because it doesn't have the slash on the server